# how to didSelectRowAt in multiple cell?

Tags: swift, swift3

I will paste some of my code

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if menu == "your_products"{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VendorTableViewCellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! VendorTableViewCell
        let vendor = self.vendors![indexPath.row]
        cell.setVendor(vendor: vendor)
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventTableViewCellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! EventTableViewCell
        cell.setEvent(event: self.events![indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

how to access each section and each row through last function didSelectRowAtIndexPath using indexPath.section and indexPath.row in multiple cell?

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: false)
   print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
}
```

Comment: Check your UITableView selection property should not be none.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line  `self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: false)`

```
 @objc func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
        {
            print(indexPath.row)
            print(indexPath.section)
       }
```

Comment: when i tap cell, the result is not there

Comment: @IrwanMadness now check

Comment: I checked but did not get any results :(

Comment: print statements will be shown only in console. please check console

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")    
}
```

I think it should work.
If this is not working then please check your delegates are connected or not.